# NMAX 2023 not starting but i hear a clicking noise

Tags: starting, starter, yamaha

I was riding it, pulled over for a quick bite and then went back to start it up it would not start, when i press the start button all i hear is a tick noise. I have a video uploaded here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU0FfDKS4QI

Comment: On this bike, is there a starter interlock that prevents starting if you don't pull the clutch lever?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @MTA It's a 125cc Scooter so it's auto.

Comment: Is there anyway you could put a multimeter on the battery to see what it reads (voltage)?

Comment: If it's auto you may need to apply the brake to start it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I done that.

Comment: @paulster2 The battery is reading 12.5v which is normal when the engine is off, so i don't its from the battery.

Comment: If it's 2023 it should be under warranty, and the dealer is the place to go.